# ValueError: Lengths must match to compare - choosing specific values from table Pandas

Tags: pandas, maxlength

I am new to programing, currently trying to compare between Y axies and X :(which has 3 values ) but it can;t compare "one to three" with the code I did.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("table3.csv").drop(columns=["STUDY_ID"]) #Had to because it just spams the colunm..
LRX= df[df['Total'] == ([['L999L', 'R999R','Xray1']])]
y = df['CD2']
x = df['LRX']
plt.xlabel('Total') ; plt.ylabel('CD2')
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
plt.show()
```

Total is the colunm holds the L999L, R999R and Xray1 inside.

What I got wrong?

```
    Total            CD8    CD2
    L999L           54.1059 261.105
    R999R           88.5381 67.6109
    Xray1           48.0809 404.211
```

Comment: Can you provide some data? First thing, that I noticed, is, that you have 3 x-axis and 1 y-axis - is that correct? Without knowing anything about the data, i would have guessed, that you want to plot 3 sets of y-axis-data over a common x-axis.

Comment: I am trying to get "L999L, R999R and Xray1" on the x axis (they are in "total" column). As for the CD2 column is actually numeric. There are many values, but I am trying to do a plot scatter between the numeric of CD2 column (which is Y axis) and the the x axis which has 3 values (str)

Comment: Then you should rewrite your line `LRX= df[df['Total'] == ([['L999L', 'R999R','Xray1']])]` It is defining LRX as the dataframe df, where the condition is fulfilled, that df.Total is equal to the 3x1 arrays. I don't understand exactly, why you want to make the 3 entries into 1, but anyway, you have to recheck that line to properly define the Column 'Total'. pd.apply(...) could be a good starting point. Still, would it be a solution to just make 3 "single" scatter plots? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: I am not sure if I can do that for my project, but I will try separatelyat first, thank you

Comment: Error is the same by the way (for the second solution as well

Comment: Again, could you provide some data or at least elaborate a bit about how the datafile looks like? That would help a lot to assist you for this problem.

Comment: Okay I added a little part of the data.  There other variants inside the "total" and other columns except CD8 and CD2. I only need CD2 "expression" and the values I mentioned in "total"

Comment: So, is 'Total' kind of a title for the index column or are the indexes still 0,1,2,...? That dataframe could be defined by `df=pd.DataFrame({'Index Title':['L999L','R999R','Xray1'],'CD2':[1,2,3],'CD8':[4,5,6]}).set_index('Index Title').rename_axis('Total')`, but that is kind of lengthy and I don't see a practical reason to rename axis and that stuff... The set_index might be useful though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this works: Define the DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Total':['L999L','R999R','Xray1'],'CD2':[48.43,24.54,26.13],'CD8':[43.51,54.12,65.13]})
```

Then you have to replace the Strings in 'Total' by numbers, so that the plot command knows, where to put the ticks (note, that a bar plot is much easier here; there, the plot command just works without this workaround):

```
ticklabels = ['L999L','R999R','Xray1']
tickdict = {'L999L': 0,'R999R': 1,'Xray1': 2}
df=df.replace({'Total':tickdict})
```

Then do the plotting, where first the x-axis is actually [0,1,2], but then the ticknames are replaced:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['Total'], df['CD2'])
plt.xlabel('Total') ; plt.ylabel('CD2')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(len(df['Total'])))
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['Total'])
ax.set_xticklabels(tickdict)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, solved. just now have to figure out how to add df.iloc instead of the valus written because  the real table has 504 rows, but most of it done, thanks

Comment: Not the most efficient solution, but still acceptable is something like df.loc[:,'CD2':'CD8'] (give all columns from 'CD2' to 'CD8'). As an alternative, df.columns[1:] gives you a list of all columns except the 'Total', from there, indexing works just as easy as in a numpy array... Have fun, and merry christmas!